# APL summing of a vector of numbers?

Tags: sum, apl

I've learnt the bare bone basics of APL and was wondering if there was anyway to display the incremental summation of a vector of numbers.

I understand +/ 1 5 6 8 would yield a grand sum of 20.

What I would like to obtain is something more along the lines of

1 6 12 20

(each number is the sum of all the numbers preceding it)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is "scan" and the simple solution is:

```
 +\ 1 5 6 8
   1 6 12 20
```

Comment: +1 When the slope operator `\\ ` is used with a left operand rather than a function `L\R`, it is called "expand", with "scan" being `f\R`.  Expand, I think fits as a nicer opposite to the "reduce" functionality of the slash `f/R`.

Comment: I agree, "expand" sounds better. In the good ol times when I learned APL, it was labeled as "scan"...

Comment: It is "scan" when used with a function, "expand" is when it's with a lefthand variable.  Just the expand makes more sense to me generally.